# Retrieving secrets from KeyVault defined in appsettings

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

In my App Service, on the Application Settings blad, if I add the following key-value, it works just fine.

```
some:secret -> @Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=...)
```

However, if I move that line to my appsettings file:

```
{
  "some": {
    "secret": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=...)"
  }
}
```

Then the retrieved value in my code for 'some:secret' would be null. Here is how I add my appsettings to configuratoin (also added `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to App Service's app settings):

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var environment = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;

                config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
                config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: false);
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            }));
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does your local machine have access to the key vault? also you have to make sure your url is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax `@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=...)` only works when deployed in an Azure AppService (or Function App) and the value will be injected like any other app settings from that blade: as ENV vars.

Your dotnet app will not see (or know) anything of the KeyVault. The retrieval of the secret is handled by AppService. That's why this also works in the same fashion for any other runtime like Java or node.

Comment: Bummer .. but what you said totally makes sense. The problem is we have so many app settings and it's hard to keep track of them, how can I move such appsettings to the source code then? I mean I could use the key vault client and write code like `if(mySettings.StartsWith("@Microsoft.KeyVault"))`, but not sure if this is the cleanest way to do so.